# Cant find the issue with my synax "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I messed up in the syntax somewhere im still kinda new to ajax, jq

I cant really figure out what the syntax error is, ive been looking at it for some time now, and thought i would ask you guys.

```
$(function (){
var $beskederUl = $('#beskeder');
//var $besked = $('#besked');
function addNyBesked(data){
    $beskederUl.append('<li>['+ data.tid +' Besked: '+ data.besked + '</li>');
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../mmudkast/code/getMessage.php',
    success: function(beskeder){
        beskeder = JSON.parse(beskeder);
        $.each(beskeder, function(i, data) {
            addNyBesked(data);
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: check your console for line number which is throwing this error

Comment: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data, i just looked up seems like there is some sort of error in my php.

Comment: hmmm, else there should be some error when your parsing your `beskeder` data. so have look at it as well

Comment: [ 
{"besked":"HEJ MIT NAVN DET ER BOB","tid":"2016-01-25 23:19:00","bruger_id":"0"},
{"besked":"HEJ MIT NAVN DET ER BOB","tid":"2016-01-25 23:19:00","bruger_id":"0"}
]
This is the output from my php.

Comment: dont see any issue there , could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Im not really sure how to make a Ajax request on jsfiddle tbh.

Comment: refer this http://jsfiddle.net/hofo/x7s9c4wL/ for mocking ajax request with your mocked json response.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x7s9c4wL/53/

Comment: well, the jsfiddle surely says there isnt any issue with your ajax code, you need to check with other piece of your code

Comment: That is a common error seen when html is outputted with json, make sure you have no html output before your json.